# Python - FindWindow by caption if caption "contains" certain values

Tags: python, string, findwindow

I am wondering how I can find a window by caption when I only partially know the string? for example if I had a window of an application called "`My 45434 Test`" the application window always has a 3 word string that starts with My and ends with Test , only the numbers generated will change. How do I get those?

```
#x = get the generated number somehow

hwndName = "My " +x + " Test"

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, hwndName)
```

Comment: You want to find the numbers or place them?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I want to find them. The window just generates the numbers itself randomly.